# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null, как решить?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Дело в следующем: есть сайт pduspb.ru, сделал страницу оплата и доставка, в меню "пункты выдачи" встроил соответствующий виджет от СДЭК, пошагово и внимательно выполнив инструкцию производителя. Проблема в том, что когда файл service.php загружаю в папку public_html - сервер не может найти виджет и выдает ошибку:
/public_html/service.php?isdek_action=getLang〈=rus:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/public_html/service.php?isdek_action=getPVZ&country=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F〈=rus:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако
Когда этот же самый service.php загружаю прям в корень сайта (рядом с public_html), виджет начинает работать на ура!
НО при обновлении любой другой страницы, сайт падает с ошибками
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
[image: 5e6f6adc151be601640179.jpeg]

Никто из знакомых более опытных специалистов не смог разобраться в чем проблема, от ТП тоже не добился вразумительной помощи. Как вылечить болячку?

Comment: а если скрипт сдека перекинуть в футер ?

Comment: Пробовал, сайт нормально работает, но виджет не запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а если убрать событие на подключение jquery, и ниже впихнуть сдек ? (тут, видимо, нужно разобраться с очередностью)

ну или, на крайняк, подключить апи на той страничке, где это нужно

Comment: Сработало...Вставил на нужную страницу...Благодарю! Неделю убил на эту фигню))